# How to avoid unnecessary Firestore reads with Cache

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have a list of trips data (Large Sets) ordered by date.

**Existing Behaviour**

I store all the trips data into SqlLite Db. For every new data added, I used to get a fcm notification and I synced only the new added data using last updated time concept. This way when ever an cx opens the app, he will always read the data from my DB, Hence saving **read** and **network** operations.

**How could i achieve the same with Firestore?**

Few problems to consider:

- Firestore get() always tries to get the data first from SERVER, even if i add CACHE to my query, how can i synced only the updated document
- In my Recyler View I want the data to be order by a field **date** not by lut(last-modified-time)
- With FireStore Snapshot Listener i can't query such a large record set.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Firestore get() always tries to get the data first from SERVER, even if I add CACHE to my query, how can I sync only the updated document?

According to the official documentation regarding [enable offline data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default.

So to use offline persistence, you don't need to make ("add") any changes to your code in order to be able to use and access Cloud Firestore data.

Also according to the official documentation regarding Query's [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()) method:

> By default, get() attempts to provide up-to-date data when possible by waiting for data from the server, but it may return cached data or fail if you are offline and the server cannot be reached. This behavior can be altered via the [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source) parameter.

So this is normal behavior. Starting with 2018-06-13 (16.0.0 SDK) is now possible to specify the source from which we want to get data. We can achieve this with the help of the [DocumentReference.get(Source source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) and [Query.get(Source source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) methods.

As you can see, we can now pass as an argument to the `DocumentReference` or to the `Query` the source so we can force the retrieval of data from the `server only`, `cache only` or attempt server and fall back to the cache.

So something like this is now possible:

```
yourDocRef.get(Source.SERVER).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        //Get data from the documentSnapshot object
    }
});
```

In this case, we force the data to be retrieved from the server only. If you want to force the data to be retrieved from the cache only, you should pass as an argument to the `get()` method, `Source.CACHE`. More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source). I also wrote an article that can help understand more clear the concept:

- [How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e)

If you want to get only `updated documents`, you can [view changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). An example from the official documentation would be:

```
db.collection("cities")
    .whereEqualTo("state", "CA")
    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
            return;
        }

        for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
            switch (dc.getType()) {
            case ADDED:
                Log.d(TAG, "New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                break;
            case MODIFIED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                break;
            case REMOVED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                break;
            }
        }

        }
    });
```

See the switch statement for every particular case? The second case will help you get only the updated data.

> In my Recyler View I want the data to be order by a field date not by lut(last-modified-time)

In this case you should create a query that allow you order the results by a specific date property. Assuming you have a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- items (collection)
        |
        --- itemId (document)
             |
             --- date: Oct 08, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
             |
             --- //other properties
```

The query like will help you achieve this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionRefference itemsRef = rootRef.collection("items");
Query query = itemsRef.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)** is also a recommended way on which you can add a timestamp to a Cloud Firestore database.

> With FireStore Snapshot Listener i can't query such a large record set.

Oh, yes you can. According this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329375/can-firebase-realtime-database-effectively-loop-through-billions-of-posts-and-re), Firebase can effectively loop through billions items. This answer is for Firebase realtime database but same principles apply to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I didn't know that Snapshot Listener can be used with Large records,  than why do FirebaseUI-Firestore doesn't support realtime updates in case of pagination ? 

So does your solution suggest to use only SnapshopListener for my use case, But SnapListener will read the entire data again if the user goes offline for 30 minutes or say quit the app etc.
----   
According to you, what would be the best way to serve large documents in recycler view by minimising the read(cost) operation ?

Comment: "Why do FirebaseUI-Firestore doesn't support realtime updates in case of pagination?" You should ask another question for that. In the meanwhile,
**[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: You can use a `SnapshopListener` if you need to get data in realtime otherwise just use a `get()` call. Firestore has offline persistence enabled by default. So once you get back online, you get all the updates from Firebase servers. The best solution? Definitely pagination!

Answer (score 8):

you can just add the source of the data to be retrived

```js
firestore.collection("yourCollection").get({source:"cache"})
```

Comment: can you please add the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use this package for that case:
[firestore_cache](https://pub.dev/packages/firestore_cache/example)

The only way to use it is to add one more document named as "status" inside the collection you want to get data from. For example, you want to get data from User collection, then you need to add document "status" ["User/status"] with a field: "updatedAt" and value which is written like this:

`updatedAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

So every time we want to add, update or delete data in current collection, we must update that field above. Otherwise, your app won't update the data automatically. Read the documentation very well.