# Firestore reads too much data (Ionic React) (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, ionic-react

So I have this app using Ionic React and Cloud Firestore as the Database. Mostly I use these codes to retrieve data:

```
const [teacher, setTeacher] = useState('');
const history = useHistory();
const [users, setUsers] = useState([{}]);

async function obtainData() {
    const querySnapshot = db.collection('TEACHER_DATA').where('email', '==', Cookies.get('email'));
    const awaitSnapshot = await querySnapshot.get();
    const data = awaitSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().name);
    setTeacher(String(data));

    const querySnapshot2 = db.collection('CLASS').where('class_teacher', '==', teacher);
    const awaitSnapshot2 = await querySnapshot2.get();
    const data2 = awaitSnapshot2.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    setUsers(data2);
}

obtainData();

return (
    <div>{
        users.map((value: any, index) => (
                <IonCard key={index} onClick={() => {
                    Cookies2.set('id', value.student_id);
                    history.push({
                        pathname: '/Student_biodata',
                        state: value.student_id
                    })
                  }} class="students">
                      <IonCardTitle>
                          {value.class_student}
                      </IonCardTitle>
                    {value.branch}
                    <IonCard id="mini-picture">
                        <IonImg src={'/assets/propic/' + value.student_id + '.jpg'}></IonImg>
                    </IonCard>
                    
                </IonCard>
            ))}
    </div>
);
```

This code shows the data I needed. However, when I checked the Firestore Usage, in 15 minutes it already has 6K reads. This is not suitable if someday the user number is increasing. My app will reach the daily limit quota in no time. The documents in my Firestore project is less than 30.

**Is there any solution for me to reduce the read in Firestore? Is there any example to make a better structure in NoSQL Firestore to reduce the read?**
I've watched the tutorial videos from Firebase about Firestore yet I still don't get it.

Comment: I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching the [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `obtainData` on every render of the page, instead of just once when the page is loaded. You can use the `useEffect` to function similar to `componentDidMount`

```
useEffect(()=>{
  obtainData();
},[]);
```

See the documentation on conditionally firing the effect which might be needed if you want the call to only happen when one of the parameters change
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: IT WORKED PERFECTLY! Thank youu!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific best way to reduce the reads in your Firestore, because it all depends on your application. For example, for Android, iOS and Web apps, Firestore supports [offline data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline), so you can cache your data for use, without having to perform get and access your database everytime - as you can get an example [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329).

To summarize, there is no better or right way of structuring your database or queries, as they need to fit your needs and what you want for your application, so, it always depend. Considering that, I would recommend you to take a look at the above mentioned links and also this similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52701789/12767257), where you can find examples of caching data to reduce reads in your database, as by your application, it seems that the `where` clauses compares with static values.